# How do I display the \subsection numbers properly in memoir amid custom formatting?

Tags: sectioning, memoir, superscripts

I am laying out a Bible using `memoir`. I have been totally happy with it except for the superscript verse numbers.

My basic setup is as follows (I do have a lot of other code in the `.tex` file  obviously, but I think these are the most relevant to the situation):

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}
    {\textsuperscript{\thesubsection}\vspace{0em}   
     \hspace{-.2em}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\subsection{} Verse 1 text with the verse number in superscript before the text. \subsection{} Verse 2 text here with a superscript verse number before the text. \subsection{} Verse 3, etc.

\end{document}
```

The end product is supposed to be the Bible text in paragraph form, with verses inline as opposed to each verse set off on their own. I got everything working properly except when I finally got the `\subsection{}` to display inline the subsection numbers turned into `o`:

[image: Notice the superscript o's where the verse numbers ought to be]

I will totally grant that, as a newbie, I may have gone about it all wrong.
Perhaps this is answered elsewhere but I am still learning the lingo and haven't yet found the right solution to the problem. Totally hoping to get this right and lay my inadequacies at the mercy of the community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: I doubt that the rewrite of `\subsection` is the best idea at all...

Using `titlesec` and `memoir` is perhaps also not the best strategy...

Now the main reason why `\thesubsection` prints `0` all the while: `\refstepcounter{subsection}` has been missing in the redefinition of `\subsection` -- the subsection counter is never increased then and remains fixed to `0` (unless explicitly changed with some `\setcounter` etc. call)

If no cross-referencing is desired, `\stepcounter{subsection}` can be used as well, but I don't recommend this there.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}

\renewcommand\thesubsection{\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}
    {\refstepcounter{subsection}\textsuperscript{\thesubsection}\vspace{0em}   
     \hspace{-.2em}\ignorespaces}

\begin{document}

\section{}
\subsection{} Verse 1 text with the verse number in superscript before the text. \subsection{} Verse 2 text here with a superscript verse number before the text. \subsection{} Verse 3, etc.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. In light of your first two statements, is there a better route you'd recommend? I don't want a simple fix to a numeration issue here either make things more difficult in the long run or break other pieces I may need. This particular project is not going to have the bells and whistles of what you'd see in a Study Bible (no extensive footnotes, no thorough cross-referencing, no blocks of information before or after books, etc.) By and large this is meant to be a reader's version, with the main body of the text as the focus.

Comment: @EddieGonzalez: The simple fix is that what can be provided on not much more than the code you have provided